# Can a 3G android phone support 4G?

Tags: 3g, 4g

I own a `Samsung galaxy note 3 N900` which is a `3G` phone.

Its specification include

***HSPA+ : HSDPA 42.2 Mbps and HSUPA 5.76 Mbps***

In my area, Airtel is providing `3G` at the speed of `2 Mbps` and `4G` at the speed of `10 Mbps`.

My phone does not support `4G` but it does support `10 Mbps` download speed.

**Will that `10 Mbps 4G` plan work on my phone or not?**

Comment: I doubt it'll work. 4G works on different frequencies and follows different techniques on how to send or receive data. If your carrier only provides 2mbps via 3G then you have to live with it. It's also interesting to provide 4G at such a low speed, because it spoils the benefit (faster transmission) by limiting it to a speed lower than HSPA+ (which does not require an additional antenna).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your phone doesn't support 4G it supports 3G++ which almost 4g and supports high speed downloads , the short unswer to your question is you can't use the 4g plan proposed by your carrier due to your phone's hardware limitation.
the bright side is HSPA+ is not so bad you will not notice the difference.